# "In the next two weeks" vs. "next two weeks"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time

Which one of the following is correct if the writer intends to say *a week after next week*?

> - My friend and I decided to go to the beach in the next two weeks.
> - My friend and I decided to go to the beach next two weeks.
> - My friend and I decided to go to the beach in the coming next two weeks.

Comment: Still not clear. Did they intend to go for a week IN two week's time, or for two weeks in a week's time or just go ONCE in two week's time?

Comment: The writer intends to say - They decided to go to the beach next next week. Like now is 22/ Feb, they want to go on two weeks from now.

Comment: Why is my question closed? I am asking something related to grammar rite? Please advice

Comment: In two weeks time, the week after next, two weeks from now.
- I agree, I also do not understand why this was closed.

Comment: Me neither. This question isn't off-topic. ... What about: *in two weeks from now*

Comment: @Em1 please discuss that issue in Meta where there is a question about the topic. And don't answer questions in comments if the question is closed

Answer (score 6):

Promoting a comment to an answer:

Are your friends planning a single trip to the beach or plan to spend one week or two weeks beginning in 14 days?

In the mean time I would suggest any of these:

We have decided to go to the beach

- in two weeks' time - *trip starts in approximately 14 days and can be 1 day*
- two weeks from now - *trip starts on this weekday 14 days from now and can be 1 day*
- the week after next - *trip starts in 8-14 days and sounds to me it will last a week*

Comment: Hi mplungjan. Sorry, the writer's intention aren't the 3 you have listed. He wants to say - They planned to go to the beach on 8 of March (considering today is 23 Feb). Please advice

Comment: That would be the second, two weeks from now

Answer (score 3):

*"My friend and I decided to go to the beach in the next two weeks."* This is a grammatical sentence, but it means that my friend and I decided to go to the beach some time during the next two weeks. If you want to refer to the week after next, then you should say *"My friend and I decided to go to the beach the week after next"*.

Comment: +1 Ha! Your analysis seems to have got a point a missed there.

Comment: I find that "My friend and I decided to go to the beach the week after next" suit the writer's intention.

Comment: Kris: What do you mean in your comment?

Comment: "Ha! Your analysis seems to have got a point **I** missed there." That should set right the typo. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This answer accepts, corrects and expands on the others. Here is a fuller list of correct ways to say it:

- My friend and I decided to go to the beach the week after next.
- My friend and I decided to go to the beach in two weeks' time. *(An apostrophe is required here, though often people forget it.)*
- My friend and I decided to go to the beach two weeks from now.
- My friend and I decided to go to the beach in two weeks.